# Can anybody tell me on which org I have to create connected app?

Tags: rest-api

I want to integrate two salesforce org so that I can show the data of source org in the target org via VF page. Please tell me on which org should I create connected app, source org and target org ?

Answer (score 2):

It doesn't matter. You can place it in either org, or even one in each org if you wanted to. Note that only the org in which the Connected App is created in can change the Client ID/Client Secret.

Comment: and can you please tell me in Oauth callback url, the salesforce instance url should be of source org or target org ?

Comment: @VivekJaiswal You should be able to just use login.salesforce.com, I believe. I'm looking for the docs now.

Comment: @VivekJaiswal Looks like the full URL you can use by default is `https://login.salesforce.com/services/oauth2/success`

Comment: Thanks a Lot sir :)

Answer (score 0):

you should be creating it in target org. Rule is simple:

whom to access- connected app should be setup there

who is accessing- consumer or client

Comment: This is not correct.